# What environmental variables can affect the successful execution of a stored procedure?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, stored-procedures

Where the  environment is either a sproc called via an ASP.NET Website or directly from within SQL management studio.

I have developed a copy routine which copies a hierarchy (of folders and files for example) from a specified source to a specified destination.  I have implemeted this using both a recursive solution (i.e. using nested stored proc calls)  and an alternative which flattens the hierarchy of folders and files, firstly, and then -  by way of a lookup - reasserts the hierarchy during copying to its destination.

When the copy routine (in both its incarnations) is executed from within SSMS, it works absolutely perfectly and the copying is completely successful.   However, when invoked from within the ASP.Net Website,  copying occurs only to a certain depth and then stops.  No errors are returned and no exceptions are thrown. Logging indicates that copying stops at the same time and same depth for both incarnations of the sproc, when it fails.

Is there an issue with a transaction scope, buffer issues, asserting allowable execution times,  LINQ to SQL limitiations or cached execution plans

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you're just hitting the default timeout?

Comment: @brumScouse How long does this process normally take? Hours, minutes, seconds?

Comment: SSMS never times out, .NET will do by default in 30 seconds (CommandTimeout property)

Comment: did you tried stepping into sproc

Comment: @Jon C, the process takes seconds.   I am completely at a loss as to why it succeeds in one context and not the other.

Comment: @gbn - There are no timeout exceptions raised.  This occurs in 2 hosted environments as well

Comment: @Brijesh - I am logging the various exceution stages to a fine grain level.

Comment: @brumScouse Anything in the SQL logs? Are you running this code in a separate thread? and finally, any issues with the security context it's running under? Trying changing your app pool account to a full access account just to see if there's any difference

Comment: I have used both cassini (not configurable?) and IIS7 with no security limitations.  I have just checked the logs...Nothing....!  Im not running the code in a separate thread, nothing exceptional going on.  The call to invoke the sproc is brokered bythe code-gen'd classes that LINQ to SQL dbml conjures up.

Comment: Have you tried running SQL Profiler, to see if the command that's being issued from ASP.NET is what you expect?

Comment: @RickNZ. Yes I have profiled it too.  Specifically checking errors, and values which are passed to the sproc.   Someone mentioned paramter sniffing to me and SQL server making a balls up of the execution plan, so I copy input variables into locally scoped variables, I have also tried the WITH RECOMPILE instruction to no avail.

Comment: @everyone - Also pronlonged the time out time for the DataContext to 3 minutes which is about 2 orders of magnitude more than necessary (according to execution summary)

Comment: .Net SQL connections are by default created with a different set of connection options than SSMS - notably `ARITHABORT` - assuming the defaults are in use, .Net and SSMS will be using different query plans because of this (although these plans may or may not be identical). Howerver, this doesn't sound like an issue of performance but of logic. Can you post some code demonstrating what fails?

Comment: @brumScouse Could you try to bypass the L2S and see what SqlCommand/SqlConnection classes produce? Just for troubleshooting.

Comment: @Ed - I wouldn't rule out logic but as the the sproc executes succesfully everytime from SSMS, it makes me think something else is a foot.  Also the 2 different implentations I have knocked up, which both work in SSMS  can't both be wrong...can they (not ruling this out at all)  I have messed with ARITHABORT to no avail...

Comment: @Jon C - I'll give that a whirl now.

Comment: @Jon C -  Using SqlCommand/SqlConnection directly works.....Ok this is good, but also bad.  Because I dont know why l2s route doesnt work.  I dont know where to start my analysis (other than profiling which didn't yield much?) Any ideas.  Thanks for your interesst guys.

Comment: @brumScouse We're getting it narrowed down at least :) Again, just for troubleshooting. Can you try L2Q with a different SPROC, like one that just returns a string "test" or something simple to see if it's affecting all SPROCs or maybe can narrow it down to something in the troubled sproc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In providing a broad answer.  The fact that isolating L2S and calling the sproc directly via ADO.NET api, provided a working solution and in so doing, highlighted at least one variable which can affect the succesful execution of  a stored proc.  Jon C deserve some plaudits here.